# How do I figure out the correct polarity of a DC barrel connector

Tags: multimeter, polarity

I'm in the U.S. and I bought a digital wall clock from the U.K. which came with an AC adapter with input 230V/50Hz/90mA and output 9V/800mA. Now I could get a transformer to convert 120V to 230V but that means connecting the already bulky adapter to another transformer and it will look hideous. Here is how far I've gotten but I'm stuck now...

The connector in the clock is a barrel type connector. First, I got a universal AC power supply for the U.S. with 120V input and an voltage output control (which includes the 9V that I need) and 1200mA output. After I received this, it looked fine and one of the barrels seemed to fit, but it required setting the correct polarity.

Next, I bought a multimeter which I got today. I set it to DC and tried both combinations of touching the black and red lines to the middle pin in the clock and to the round outer wall. When I put the black to the outside wall and the red to the inner pin, I get 0mV, but when I put black to the middle pin and red to the outer wall, I get about 1.0 mV.

Does this mean that the clock requires positive polarity or negative polarity?

Edit: Neither the power supply that shipped with the clock nor the clock instructions or case show the clock's expected polarity :( I emailed the manufacturer and they didn't answer this question.

Comment: Hi us2012, when you say the power supply is broken, I'm not sure what you mean - the clock is not powered on

Comment: Maybe you have it set to AC? Did the multimeter cost more than the clock?

Comment: The multimeter is definitely set to DC. I tried the multimeter on a battery and it worked

Comment: @us2012, Andy: "in the clock"

Comment: @Andy it's a $200 clock :)

Comment: @Ignacio Oh, right. I missed that, sorry.

Comment: If it's a $200 clock, the manufacturer of the clock should be fairly willing to tell you what sort of adapter you need. Adapters are a cheap commodity item, and you probably won't hear from that manufacturer (who probably just relabels).

Comment: @Scott I will try again...

Comment: Keep in mind that if you get a AC-AC adapter in the US, you'll be feeding the clock 60Hz (instead of the 50Hz it was designed for) and it may count fast due to that.

Comment: @Shamtam thanks, I will try to get a 50Hz adapter

Comment: @eydelber - you will have trouble finding an adapter which will produce 50 Hz from a 60 Hz supply, unless you get an inverter.  In the old day's they'd actually do this with a motor driving a generator.

Comment: @Chris Thanks. My understanding is that the different Hz issue generally affects motorized clocks, so I'm hoping that a digital clock won't be affected. We'll see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant answer in the comments so i will answer here.

You said the specification says "Output: 9V~800mA". The ~ means it is AC output.
So try setting the multimeter in AC mode. That is probably why it doesn't show the polarization.

Comment: That's surprising, I thought just about every device like a clock takes DC input?

Comment: Great point.  If it's and AC supply, there will be no polarity to read!

Comment: So if polarity doesn't matter for AC, then all I need is a universal barrel adaptor that inputs 110/120V and outputs 9V/800mA in AC and not DC? I'm not sure what to search for (e.g. "ac to ac") to buy one

Comment: just search for 9V AC Adapter, and be sure to check if it really outputs AC and has at least 800mA.

Comment: something like this http://www.ebay.com/itm/9V-AC-Adapter-Power-Supply-for-Linksys-9VAC-1000mA-9V-1Amp-model-AD-9-1C-/231025209821?pt=US_Server_Power_Supplies&hash=item35ca2cf1dd

Comment: Thanks, a couple more questions: my understanding is that if amps are too low that's a problem, but too high is okay right? For example, I found one that is: "Output Voltage 9VAC, Output Current 3333mA, Hz 60... Tip Size 2.1 x 5.5 x 10mm" Is 3333mA too much for something expecting 800mA? Also, I need to match the tip size -- I have a caliper, do you know how I should measure it to see if the 2.1x5.5x10 matches?

Comment: More current on the adapter means more room for stronger devices. Your clock will use 800mA of the current. It will work. It depends on the caliper size, usually they are too big to measure such a small hole. You could try finding something that perfectly fits in the hole, and measure the thickness of that thing. As you can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector the most used are with tip size of 2.1 and 2.5mm

Comment: Thanks, my caliper shows the outer diameter is 5.5mm, but as you said, it can't fit inside for the inner diameter, but it looks closer to 2.1mm rather than 2.5mm.

Comment: To summarize, I need an Input: AC 110/120V, Output: AC 9V (50Hz ideally) with >= 800mA and a 2.1mm x 5.5mm x ~<12mm barrel length female plug. I will be accepting yours as the answer, thanks!!

Comment: Everything is correct, except you need a male plug. The clock has a female plug. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

On the power pack, you're looking for a symbol like the link either on a label on in the plastic. This tells you that the center pin is positive and the outside is negative. This is more likely but it is possible to have it the other way round where the plus an minus are swapped. The clock may also have it somewhere on a label or near the socket.

http://www.accesscomms.com.au/images/reference/powerplug-positive.jpg

**Edit from comments:**
From the part numbers, it's all AC.

A tutorial on AC/DC labelling...
http://www.harmonycentral.com/t5/Technology-Computers/External-Power-Supply-Essentials/ba-p/34655117

Comment: I should have mentioned it in the original question, but the problem is that the power pack that shipped with the clock doesn't show its polarity and I emailed the manufacturer and they didn't respond

Comment: Do you have a part number of the clock or the power adapter?

Comment: Here's everything I can read off it: Nextime Model No 2897 9V~ 800mA, RoHS AC Adaptor, Model YHA0900800G-33, Input 230V~50Hz 90mA, Output: 9V~800mA. This is the part connected to the barrel connector. But then this adaptor goes into some sort of fuse adaptor: PowerConnections Harlow England, Fit 3/5 A Fuse, 250V~3A, BS1363-5

Comment: I wonder, can I test the polarity of the original wall clock 230V AC adaptor instead of testing the polarity of the clock?

Comment: As @user2613971 said, the whole thing is 9V AC.

Comment: The universal adaptor I have doesn't say if output is AC or DC, it just says: Output:3/4.5/6/7.5/9/12V 1200mAmax and then it has a solid line on top of a dashed line. Will this work for the clock?

Comment: Nope. The solid line/dashed line is DC. They represent the voltage waveforms. A 110V AC to 9V AC shouldn't be too hard to find though.

Comment: I see, so that means my adaptor is wrong, and I need a universal AC adapter.

Comment: Does anyone have any recommendations for an AC-AC adaptor? I can't seem to find one on Amazon

Comment: Thanks, I read the linked article and it was very interesting

Comment: These guys have one. http://www.connevans.co.uk/viewProduct.do?id=1577620 They're in the UK though. I'm in Aus so I keep getting bumped on to au sites when I try our suppliers. You may have luck with element14 (Newark / farnell). Or good ol' ebay... http://compare.ebay.com.au/like/400471768035?ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&cbt=y&_lwgsi=y&lpid=45&item_id=400471768035

Comment: @eydelber: From some of the comments, it appears that this clock requires a 9 volt AC input - if so, it is quite possible that it uses the AC line frequency as a time reference.  If this is the case, the clock will not be usable in North America, as it will be designed for 50 Hz line frequency, and we have 60 Hz here - the clock will show 50 minutes per hour.

Comment: @PeterBennett Hey Peter, the AC adapter is in the mail, so we'll soon find out. I'll post back for the curious...

Comment: @PeterBennett Great news, I got the $10 plug from eBay and it fits and works great! The Hz didn't seem to play a role. I left it running overnight and the time is still correct today. I don't know why my question was downvoted, but I know that I learned a lot. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:  Buy whatever transformer you need to in order to plug the original adapter into your wall socket, and measure the polarity on the connector of the adapter when it is plugged in.  Many such power adapters are good for 240V and 120V, so a passive travel adapter may be all you need.  Even if the adapter doesn't work right at 120V, it shouldn't be damaged, and the output might be good enough for you to understand the polarity.

Comment: That makes sense, so I would just plug the original adapter in, through a transformer, but not connect it to the clock, and then test the adapter's output polarity?

Comment: yup, that's how you'd do it.  If you use the right transformer, guaranteed correct answer.  Just pay attention to the polarity of your meter probes!

Comment: Thanks, now again, I'm a noob, so how do I interpret the results - let's say I put the black wire inside the plug and red outside and it reads positive, what does that mean? And do I need to test both combinations or will they just be negative inverses of each other?

Comment: If the black wire is connected to something that says "Ground", "GND", "Common", "CMN", or something like that, that would mean that the outside is positive compared to the inside, and you have a "Center negative" power supply.  Chances are you will find a "center positive" so for maximum clarity, you want to put the black wire on the outside, and the red wire on the inside.  If it reads positive, you have "center positive", and if negative, "center negative"

Comment: Yes, the black wire was connected to COM in the multimeter. I will confirm the readings...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't mean anything. You will need to open the clock and trace one of the connections to an IC, electrolytic, or some other polarized, non-reversible device. (Most barrel connections are center-positive, but don't take that as a universal absolute.)

Comment: Argh, I was hoping it wouldn't get that complicated because I'm not sure what I'm going to be looking at when I open it. I had assumed that polarity could be understood just by touching the two metal parts of the clock input.

Comment: What does the polarity indicator on the current wall wart say?

Comment: That's the root problem - the wall wart that shipped with the clock doesn't have the universal polarity indicator. I emailed the manufacturer but they didn't respond

Comment: Follow the traces either to an IC, or to a device with a polarity indicator (thick line, positive/negative sign, etc.) and find the datasheet for it. If it's a diode or LED, ignore it and keep looking.